# Adding Data File into Two Seperate 2D Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I am having some trouble with a Java program. I have a txt data file, which I will display, that I need to add into two separate arrays. The text file is 8 lines long that is supposed to go into two separate 4x4 matrices. A little background info on this program, reads in two arrays, compares them and outputs the largest elements of the same index and outputs them in a separate array. I somehow cannot seem to figure out how to add the data file into two separate arrays. My code is below, thanks in advance.

Data File:

```
2 7 6 4
6 1 2 4
9 7 2 6
8 3 2 1
4 1 3 7
6 2 3 8
7 2 2 4
4 2 3 1
```

Code:

```
public class prog465a
{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner inFile = null; 
        try 
        { 
            inFile = new Scanner(new File("prog465a.dat.txt")); 
        } 

        catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("File not found!"); 
            System.exit(0); 
        } 

        int[][] firstData = new int[4][4]; 
        int[][] secondData = new int[4][4]; 
        int[][] finalData = new int[4][4];
        for (int i = 0; i< 8; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
               if (i < 4 && j < 4){ //Trying to add first four lines to one matrix
                   firstData[i][j] = inFile.nextInt();  
                } else if (i >= 4 && j >= 4)
                {
                    secondData[i][j] = inFile.nextInt();           
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i< 8; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
               if (firstData[i][j] >= secondData[i][j])
               {
                   firstData[i][j] = finalData[i][j]; 
                }
                else if (secondData[i][j] >= firstData[i][j])
                {
                    secondData[i][j] = finalData[i][j]          
                }

            }
        }

          for ( int c = 0 ; c < finalData.length ; c++ )
      {
         for ( int d = 0 ; d < finalData.length ; d++ )
         {
               System.out.print(finalData[c][d]+" ");        
            }
         System.out.print("\n");
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is that you are trying to parse a file with 8 rows and 8 column..

**change this:**

```
 int[][] finalData = new int[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i< 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
```

**to:**

```
 int[][] finalData = new int[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i< 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
```

that means 8 rows of file with 4 column each.

Also on the second part of your forloop again you are trying to get 8x8 matrix it should be 4x4..

**change:**

```
for (int i = 0; i< 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
           if (firstData[i][j] >= secondData[i][j])
           {
               firstData[i][j] = finalData[i][j]; 
            }
            else if (secondData[i][j] >= firstData[i][j])
            {
                secondData[i][j] = finalData[i][j]          
            }

        }
    }
```

**to:**

```
for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {

           if (firstData[i][j] >= secondData[i][j] )
           {
               finalData[i][j] = firstData[i][j]; 
            }
            else if (secondData[i][j] >= firstData[i][j])
            {
                finalData[i][j] = secondData[i][j] ;         
            }

        }
    }
```